# php xpath search div value and find value of addition element

Tags: php, xpath, domdocument

I am trying to read the data-id value from xml as below.

example data is like this:

```
<div class="youtube-player" data-id="123456789012"></div>
```

My current PHP looks like this.

```
$doc->loadHTML($content); 
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);    
$special = $xpath->query("//div[@class='youtube-player']"); 
foreach($special as $searchNode) {
    $youcode = $searchNode->data-id;
    echo "<script>console.log('Check Data-id:');</script>";
    echo "<script>console.log('$youcode');</script>";
}
```

Seems I am just stuck how to get the string from the data-id part.
This is running as a plugin inside Wordpress.

Answer (score 2):

You should use [`getAttribute()`](http://php.net/manual/en/domelement.getattribute.php) to getting value of attribute. The target part of code should changed to

```
$youcode = $searchNode->getAttribute("data-id");
```

Comment: Thank you that's perfect. Seems I have a little more to learn.